# Android backup service

Tags: android, backup

Is it possible to invoke "bu" (backup) service directly from android app or native shell on non-rooted phone? I know it is possible to do it via "adb shell backup". However, the main requirement is to be able to initialise this request without any prior usb connection.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/backup.html#RequestingBackup

Comment: Backup manager (or bmgr) cannot invoke backup/restore of application's data other than the one from which you call it. However, the "adb shell backup" (or actual "bu" service) gives you a possibility to create backup of any application currently installed on your phone.